# PHP: How to detect/parse all TAGS in rss/feed XML?

Tags: php, xml, rss, tags

I'm testing rss feed reader, from a sample.
It uses:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($url);

$items = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    $item_title = $items->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link  = $items->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc  = $items->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

When i check the XML, it has another Tags like:

- Date
- Image Link

How can i call these all other tags? Because i can't call myself.
For example, for the 'date', i can't use `getElementsByTagName('date')`.
It showing error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object`

- So, is there fixed names for tags?
- If so, what are these?
- (or) How can i know/ parse/ detact/ extract all available tags inside XML?

Comment: Your problem isn't too clear. Why aren't you using the same method for the other tags?

Comment: Yes because i don't know how to call other tags like. For example, for the "date", this one `getElementsByTagName('date')` or `getElementsByTagName('lastUpdated')` don't work. It is showing: `Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object`. I completely don't know about this RSS/XML topic.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml) That might be a better option if you aren't too far along in your project

Answer (score 1):

You can access each node recursively and you can choose from which one to get your data by checking if the tag name matches your desired one :

```
$indent = 0;
$tab = 4;
function indent($indent){
    $r = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$indent;$i++)
        $r .= " ";
    return $r;
}
function parseNode($node){
    global $indent,$tab;
    if(!$node->hasChildNodes())
        return;
    $indent += $tab;
    // if($note->tagName == "item") do something special
    echo indent($indent)."<".$note->nodeName.">";
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $c) 
        parseNode($c);

    echo indent($indent)."</".$note->nodeName.">";
    $indent -= $tab;
}
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($url);
parseNode($xmlDoc);
```

Comment: It showing `<> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <> <>  <> <> <>  ` What should i modify?

Comment: In the `function parseNode()`, what is `$note->tagName` ? There is no predefined `$note` or `tagName`.. ;(